# Как сравнить input?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть input с id='inp' и name='admpnl' в котором пользователь написал например hdltn, а функция сравнивает, совпадает то что написал пользователь или нет (совпадение - https). Если совпадает, то перенаправить на страничку в браузере: example.com/panel .
А если не совпадает, то вывести alert.

Comment: Совпадает ли то что написал пользователь с `https`? Причём тут `name='admpnl'`?

Comment: Я просто новичёк и не знал какую нужно оставить, id  или name поэтому оставил 2

Comment: А где ответ на первый вопрос? С чем нужно сравнивать ввод юзера? Со словом `https` или `hdltn`?

Comment: Со словом https

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onchange="changeImput(this.value)"  />

<script>
function changeImput(val) {
  if (val === 'hdltn') window.location = 'http://example.com/panel'
  else alert('error')
}
</script>
```

upd: версия с кнопкой..

```
<input type="text" id="imp" />
<button onclick="changeImput()">But</button>

<script>
function changeImput() {
  const val = document.querySelector('#imp').value
  if (val === 'hdltn') window.location = 'http://example.com/panel'
  else alert('error')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно меня поняли, но не могли бы вы сделать кнопку которая вызывает этот if? Просто я новичёк в программировании

Comment: Ну, тоесть кнопка перенаправляет на веб сайт если совпадает, а если не совпадает, то при нажатии на кнопку выводит alert

Comment: Извините, но меня не перенаправляют на сайт, я ничего не изменял в вашем коде, но у меня почему-то не перенаправляется на другой сайт.

Comment: @DirfectGigi Вы вводите "hdltn" и ничего?)

Comment: Всё равно не работает :(

Comment: hdltn вот, я вот это ввожу

Comment: У меня оба примера работают. Возможно, в консоле вы видите ошибки?

Comment: Тут такое дело, я с телефона и я не знаю как на нём посмотреть консоль

Comment: @DirfectGigi вы занимаетесь программированием с телефона?.. Боюсь, вы могли совершить вообще любую ошибку, предположу, что у вас даже синтаксис не подсвечивает на телефоне) Скобку пропустили или еще где опечатка

Comment: Я вставляю ваш код на своём сайте который стоит на Google Sites

Comment: Я полностью копирую ваш код и ничего не пропускаю

Comment: У меня максимум может не скопироватся начало или конец кода, но я их проверил они в норме

Comment: Без консоли (Ctrl+Shift+C) вы врятле найдете в чем проблема)

Comment: <input type="text" id="imp" />
<button onclick="changeImput()">But</button>

<script>
function changeImput() {
  const val = document.querySelector('#imp').value
  if (val === 'https') window.location = 'http://example.com/panel'
  else alert('error')
}
</script>

Comment: Вот что у меня написано

Comment: Зашел в гугл, и боюсь, у вас проблемы.. https://overcoder.net/q/380508/как-вставить-код-javascript-на-страницу-сайтов-google

Comment: Ууууууууууууууууу.... Я в этом тем более не понимаю...

Comment: Если кратко, гугл не будет просто так работать с вашим произвольным JS кодом) А если и будет, то изолированно, без доступа к DOM